# handle socket connection in background service for api 28

Tags: android, background-service

Before api 28 i can simply start a background service and continuously listen to a socket connection for any incoming data 
however in recent changes in api 28 as shown here https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services
i can no longer start a background service in android 9 unless it covers only one of the following case

> Under certain circumstances, a background app is placed on a temporary
>   whitelist for several minutes. While an app is on the whitelist, it
>   can launch services without limitation, and its background services
>   are permitted to run. An app is placed on the whitelist when it
>   handles a task that's visible to the user, such as:
>
> Handling a high-priority Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) message.
>   Receiving a broadcast, such as an SMS/MMS message.
>   Executing a PendingIntent from a notification.
>   Starting a VpnService before the VPN app promotes itself to the 
>     foreground.

The only option i found is to start service as a foreground .
I already found some alternative like using JobScheduler or WorkManger but i don't think they can cover my requirements

so my question is there any other way to listen for a socket connection that targets  android 9 (api 28) other than using foreground service?

Comment: what do you mean what is the best practice? There is only one option and you already know what that is

Comment: u mean foreground service?

Answer (score 0):

Nice Question. I have also survived with service. Foreground service also not a better solution for Android 9. Cause due to system resource circumstances foreground service also can be killed.

Better you can use `WorkManager`.  It will give you a nice flavor.

**Give it to a try.**

Comment: i am not sure but i don't think i can use workmanager for a long running task like background service

Answer (score 0):

i used foreground service for android with work manager.If you are concerned about the shutdown of the service, check the running status of the service with periodic work manager.Like every 10 min or 1 hour .Because work manager is not compatible with the logic of working like socket, you can do it periodically or you can have it done once.

```
Soo
Socket listen every time
Work manager work by periodicly or one shot
Service works every time;
```

Final result every time worker and ever time listener is perfect match for like firebase push notification service.

```
for a good working cycle
Service Continuously works and listens with a socket inside.
The work manager checks periodically whether the service is running, in case the service is closed.
```